# How to fix responsive images not resolving to correct desktop size

Tags: html, css

I have placed responsive images next to text testimonials but they are not displaying at the correct maximum size on a desktop. They are displaying bigger, and I want them at their maximum size only, which is 451 px. The first one, for example, displays at 567 px, despite setting it (obviously incorrectly) in the code. You can see here: https://www.artisanbelle.com (scroll down to the light grey box of testimonials to see).

I have tried the following code (I've only reproduced the first testimonial block, the others are just repeats of it):

````
    <div class="testimonial-container">

    <div class="pic-testimonial">
      <div class="testimonial-imga"><figure class="photo1"><img class="testimonial-photo" src="http://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/amandac.jpg" alt="Amanda C"></figure> </div>
        <div class="testimonial-texta"><p>"I saw these and couldn't resist. They are even more beautiful on. The natural stones have a lovely depth of colour. The quality is amazing and great value for money. These would make a great present." - Amanda</p> </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    ```

    ```
    .testimonial-container {
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    /* For mobile */
    .testimonial-imga, .testimonial-imgb, .testimonial-texta, .testimonial-textb {
            width: 100%;
        }

    .pic-testimonial {
        padding:15px;
        background-color: #DFE3E6;
    }

    .testimonial-imga, .testimonial-imgb {
        float: left;
    }


    .testimonial-texta, .testimonial-textb {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    `   background-color: #DDE1E4;
        width: 50%
    }


    .pic-testimonial::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }

    testimonial-photo {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* for desktop */
        .testimonial-imga, .testimonial-texta, .testimonial-imgb, .testimonial-textb  {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .testimonial-imga {
            float: left;
        }

        .testimonial-imgb {
            float: right;
        }

        .testimonial-texta {
            float: right;
            padding: 15px;
    `       background-color: #DFE3E6;
            width: 50%
        }

        .testimonial-textb {
            float: left;
            padding: 15px;
    `       background-color: #F3F3F3;
            width: 50%
        }

      .photo1 {
        display: block;
        height: 451px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .testimonial-photo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    }
````

Expected results - images to be max height 451px, with correct width (varies)
Actual result - images are all bigger. The first one is for example 567px

Answer (score 0):

This solve your problem:

```
.testimonial-photo{
    max-height:451px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

edited

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't do anything.

Comment: pay attention, I've inspected your the code in your website and you have `testimonial-photo {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 451px;

}` with missing dot (.testimonial-photo)

Comment: Thanks. I just fixed the dot, but it still hasn't resolved the image problem.

Comment: really strange, now I've see your image at 100%, with correct aspect ratio and a max height of 451px, tested with chrome, maybe try to force refresh (cmd+shift-r / ctrl+shift+r).

Comment: That is strange. I have tested it on FF, chrone and edge and they all show the bigger size still, even after clearing cache. Also, I have the original image opened 100% in an image program on my computer and it (the original) is definitely smaller. Plus I print screened, cut out the image and compared the size, and the web image is larger.